# what causes slow ssh connection and slow mysql connection on local server?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ssh, local-area-network

There's a huge latency when I try to connect to our server (Ubuntu server 192.168.53.1) through SSH from a client PC (windows 7 + putty: 192.168.53.X) in a LAN. 
It takes like a minute for the password prompt to show up. There's also a huge latency when I try to connect to the mySQL database running on the same server. 
This server is also running SAMBA but this is running very smooth.

Here you can find our network diagram:
[link text](http://www.zap.be/network.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit  here  /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change or add  UseDNS no

After that restart service  ssh demon

then tray again  if  problem is some

Tray to  change or  add  /etc/ssh/ssh_config
in the host * section

CheckHostIP no

Comment: Thanks, UseDNS no fixed the SSH problem! But i'm still having latency problems when connecting to the mySQL server or when I use remote desktop (VNC), any idea?

Answer (score 2):

mysql service should be started with --skip-name-resolve or you can set the option in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. For ssh you should make sure UseDNS is set to "no" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: skip-name-resolve was allready in my.cnf could it be something else?

Comment: any ipv4 address conflicts on that lan segment?

Comment: No, but the ip of our server is changed. Before it was 10.0.0.12 because it was on another network. Now it is 192.168.53.1 I've allready changed the bind-addres to this ip in my.cnf but this makes no difference

Comment: any entries in the hosts_allow/deny file on the server that could trigger a resolve process? if negative, i suppose you already checked the icmp response times between hosts and they look ok? arping is also a good tool on lan

Comment: hosts_deny and hosts_allow are commented out. I can also ping to the server from any client.

Comment: should you tie the problem to subnet reconfiguration? I mean, was it working fine before?

Comment: thinking maybe you have an internal dns used by the services on your network that you should also update

Comment: It was indeed working perfectly before, so my thought is that the previous IP is hardcoded somewhere in the server. But I'm not sure where. /etc/resolv.conf returns 2 dns services (one for the first router and one for the second router which is connected to the internet)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reduce latency to my ubuntu server with the following:

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_low_latency
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling
```

or like this if you want it to stick across reboots:

```
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

RTT on ping went from average of a couple hundred ms (max was sometimes over 1000 ms) down to 1 to 2 ms.

Comment: These are useful options, but it's important to understand what they do, and whether or not they'll help, before messing with them. (In this case as seen in the accepted answer the problem wasn't network stack latency, it was slow DNS lookups.)